# Facing "Failed to establish connection - Internal Server Error" when Integrating Gupshup with Magento"

Tags: chatbot, gupshup

I'm encountering an error while trying to integrate Gupshup with my Magento instance. Whenever I attempt to link Gupshup with my Magento admin account, I receive the following error message:

> Failed to establish connection - Internal Server Error.

I've double-checked all integration settings, ensured that the Magento admin URL is correct, and verified that there are no firewall or network restrictions blocking the connection. Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to establish a connection between Gupshup and Magento.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Are there any specific configuration settings or debugging steps I should follow to diagnose the problem?